# Prevent Direct access to original subst folder on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, subst

I have this subst rule in my Windows 10 PC.

`d:\Media => E:`

But the problem is that all search-related program shows two copy of the folder, which is annoying. Some of them have exclude directory feature, but some don't.

So is it possible to disable access to `d:\Media` folder so no one can access it directly, and only through `e:`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Subst is only pointing towards the old folder. Changing anything on the old location directly alters the subst location. This is unavoidable.

Given that subst can easily be created and deleted, I would suggest to do a `subst /d e:` before the search, and `subst e: d:\media` after the search.

Comment: I was wondering if there is something I can do with file permission (via Properties -> Security tab) in `d:\media`?

Comment: As said in my answer. Anything you change to D:\media will directly affect e:\. So either both have no access or both have access.

Comment: Ok. I guess....